# How do I open a file with an extension of .accdb?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard

I got a file contain extension of .accdb 
I don't know how to open or which software to use to read this file

Answer (score 1):

`.accdb` are most likely Access 2007/2010 database files. You can try to open them with Openoffice or Neoffice (free open source office suites).

Comment: thanx for your reply. I tried with open office 3 version but it's not open. the file is made in access 2007

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read Access databases on OSX without third party software.

There are a few commercial program's such as razorSql and MacODBC that either provide the tools to do the work, or in the latter case an ODBC driver that will allow you to do SQL work with the db.

it's not good news I'm afraid